# R extend vectors to be the same length around central value

Tags: r

Let's suppose I have a list:

```
[[1]]
 [1]  0.7125856 -1.4871811  0.6230076  1.0756424  0.8172592 -0.1327926 -0.7674947 -1.0738684  1.5706677
[10] -0.6674960

[[2]]
[1] -0.5778682 -1.1186447  0.8272505  0.5123162  0.6607654  1.6559877 -0.7961859 -0.8966686

[[3]]
 [1] -1.42867999 -0.21142100 -2.89762370  0.11036288  0.66846399 -0.77309213  0.35278541 -0.99579117 -0.73043142
[10] -0.01857864 -0.93654969  0.46751328

[[4]]
[1] -0.483896685 -0.207550362 -0.902920637 -0.008191134 -1.015636093
```

And I also have a vector with indices of so-called "central" values of vectors in this list:

```
[1] 2 4 5 1
```

What I'm trying to get is for given range (for example, 3) get subsets of vectors around those centers with the length of range in both sides. So every subset must be length of 7 and if range extends beyond length of vector there must be NAs added:

```
[[1]]
[1]         NA         NA  0.7125856 [-1.4871811]  0.6230076  1.0756424  0.8172592

[[2]]
[1] -0.5778682 -1.1186447  0.8272505  [0.5123162]  0.6607654  1.6559877 -0.7961859

[[3]]
[1] -0.2114210 -2.8976237  0.1103629  [0.6684640] -0.7730921  0.3527854 -0.9957912

[[4]]
[1]           NA           NA           NA [-0.483896685] -0.207550362 -0.902920637 -0.008191134
```

I put centers in brackets, because SO doesn't allow bold text in a code. Is there a way to do something like this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this?

Data:

```
n <- 10
x <- list(rnorm(n),rnorm(n),rnorm(n),rnorm(n))
i <- c(2,4,5,1)
r <- 3
```

Possible solution:

```
f <- function(x) ifelse((x-r):(x+r) %in% 1:n,(x-r):(x+r),NA)
tmp <- lapply(i,f)
out <- mapply("[",x,tmp)
split(out,col(out))
$`1`
[1]         NA         NA  0.8120232  0.4980624 -2.9708413  0.6754918 -0.9900322

$`2`
[1] -1.0303741 -1.7432638  0.9466315 -1.3322712 -1.7281613 -0.1951453  0.3789493

$`3`
[1] -1.4120119  0.3675425 -0.8378275 -1.1080856 -0.9369994  1.0823376  1.2194782

$`4`
[1]         NA         NA         NA  0.1757164 -1.5768032  0.3121876  0.4443616
```

Comment: Thank you, but vectors in list are not of the same length and I guess it would be problematic to equalise them

Comment: So it seems that it works, but do I understand correctly that n is not actually very meaningful? I get same results using different n

Comment: Correct. Since you didn't post a reproducible example (next time use the `dput()` function and post the output) I generated a random list of vectors, length = n. I probably should have varied n to better match your data, but as you said it should still work.